How Do I Reset My Battery Management System (BMS) After New Battery Install?
I am very new to electrical engineering. So if any additional information is needed please let me know and I can try to get it. I included the manufactures battery pack specifications bellow [IMAGE 1], everything should be the same for the new battery pack except the capacity and discharge rate
IMPROTANT:
bellow when I make the assertion that the factory blade connectors have a potential across it all the time, I am  90% sure this is true (as this is what I remember when investigating the issue). I am away from the battery packs right now so I can confirm this later this week. but please keep this in mind while reading
BACKGROUND:
This battery pack is for a robot I am working on (i'm working on software and adding some hardware components and that is where the electrical engineering part comes into play). I am adding a lot of peripherals to the robot so I wanted to upgrade the batteries inside the battery pack.
The battery pack works by plugging it into the robot, and pressing the power button twice fast but holding on the second press for about 1-2 seconds (I assume that the PCB that is on the robot that makes a direct connection with the battery pack prevents electricity from flowing until the communication made by the power button on the battery pack has been completed because as I explain later the blade connectors of the factory battery always have a voltage difference when disconnected and the power button is never pressed).
I sent it out to a company that said they could put better batteries in my battery pack. which they replaced the 18650 batteries with new ones that have a little higher capacity and the max discharge rate is 30 amps per 18650. When I got the battery pack back, the LED lights that will turn on to indicate the battery percentage level when you press the power button once, only had the first LED flashing (which on the factory battery means the battery is dead) and no voltage difference is being read from the blade connectors (I have another battery that came straight from the factory where there is always a voltage potential between the blade connectors).
I proceeded to take the battery pack apart [IMAGE 2]. There are voltage readings coming from each pin on the board (labeled V1-V8) and also the voltage difference of the V- and V+ are present. the voltage difference form the positive to negative (V+ and V- respectively) was approximately 30.7 Volts which was slightly higher than my factory battery pack which was at 30.5 Volts at the time and the LED indicators had 3 solid circles (meaning the battery was at somewhere between 51-75%). The PCB board that is controlling the LEDs is powered and communicated with by the 7 pin connector [IMAGE 4] that is on the opposite side of the BMS board from the blade connectors . I am unsure if this information is useful, but when I plug in the battery pack to charge, the single LED blinks like it is charging for about 10-20 seconds, and then it goes off.
I am unsure if there is a database, search engine, website to look up PCBs (or if they are even public). But I tried looking up the numbers and letters/identifiers that are on the BMS board by the blade connectors [IMAGE 3] and cannot find any schematics or details of it through google (and from my experience in other fields, more detailed things are not able to be queried well from google's general search engine)
QUESTIONS:

I have read that the BMS typically has to be reset after new batteries are installed. there are other components on the other side of the BMS board, but I figured that whatever I need to do to reset it (if that is even the problem, I assume it is) would be on the front (as how would I access the back after I install new batteries and solder the connections).
- the question from here is, is anyone able to tell me by looking at the front alone how to reset it? I am not sure if there is a standard way that most BMS are reset. Or if I desolder the battery joints from the BMS and send a picture of the back, would that be a way for somebody to definitely tell me how to reset it by lookin at the circuit?

MY THOUGHT PROCESS:
I assume that the blinking LED is also indicative that the BMS has to be rest. If there was a potential difference between the blade connectors I wouldn't jump to this assumption, but since both are happening this is assumption. In other words, I assume that the blinking light might be a signal to use that we need to reset the BMS, and that its not allowing electricity to get to the blade connectors because the BMS needs to recalibrate.
the only other thing I can see going wrong is if the circuit components got damaged, but that doesn't seem likely, correct? as it is very common for BMS's to need to be reset?
SUMMARY:

something on the BMS seems to be preventing the blade connectors from having a voltage difference

if the problem is resetting the BMS, is it either internally on the BMS or by some communication form an external source? in other words, do I just have to short a pin? or do I have to have a signal generator or can I use a microcontroller to reset it?

looking at the circuit alone we should be able to tell how to reset it right? even If it is hard to do? that is, we should have to look at integrated circuits, etc?


is there a good source to look up PCBs schematics? Or are most of them unique and not in databases and I must get the schematics and details directly from the manufacturer if they are willing to supply it?


[IMAGE 1]

[IMAGE 2]

[IMAGE 3]

[IMAGE 4]

